CÓMO CONVERTIR DE byte[] DE C# A SDOKCNTBINS DE SAP
Tengo un aplicación .net que manda datos a SAP por medio de SAP Conector 3.0. Entre los datos, tengo que mandar n ficheros que voy obteniendo de un dataTable. Si intento pasar el fichero directamente:
// Contenido del fichero
long ll_Largo = lector.GetBytes(3, 0, null, 0, 0);
byte[] bFichero = new byte[ll_Largo];
lector.GetBytes(3, 0, bFichero, 0, (int)ll_Largo);
Fila.SetValue("T_CONTENT_BIN", bFichero);

Da error, lógicamente. Necesito convertirlo antes al tipo SDOKCNTBINS, de SAP, pero no sé cómo hacerlo. He probado varias cosas, pero todas me dan error.
Por favor ¿Alguien podría explicarme cómo hacerlo?
Muchas gracias.

Estás usando alguna librería? Nunca usé eso y no encuentro nada útil

Sí, estoy usando SAP Connector 3
